# Trying to implement OAuth resource owner password flow for an Android app - can I store refresh tokens in my database?

Tags: android, database, security, authentication, oauth

I have an Android app that authenticates with my Node JS backend.

I issue an auth token and refresh token and send it to my app. I'm thinking, if the auth token expires, the client sends the refresh token to the backend for an auth token refresh. The backend then ensures the refresh token is still in the database and then sends back a new auth token.

Because lets say the user wants to revoke access to the Android app from another device (i.e. a dashboard). They basically request to have the refresh token deleted from the database, and therefore no more refreshes allowed by the Android app.

Is this a proper way to implement the flow? If it isn't, how do I properly ensure the refresh token can both be used and be revoked by the user?

Comment: Great question, I have the same one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your use-case, then this is a condition covered within  OpenID Connect. (ie You mentioned [authenticates](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/OAuth%202.0%20NOT%20an%20Authentication%20protocol) ) and is covered in [OpenID Connect Back-Channel Logout 1.0 - draft 04](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html#Validation)

"Refresh tokens issued without the offline_access property to a session being logged out **SHOULD be** revoked.

Refresh tokens issued with the offline_access property normally **SHOULD NOT** be revoked.

NOTE: An open issue for the specification is whether to define an additional optional parameter in the logout token, probably as a value in the event-specific parameters JSON object, that explicitly signals that offline_access refresh tokens are also to be revoked."

Comment: I don't quite understand what flow I'm supposed to implement to accomplish my objective. My main objective is to have persistent authentication from my Android phone to my client, i.e. with a short-lived access JWT and a long-lived refresh JWT. Where does the log out token come into play here?

Comment: OpenID Connect Back-Channel Logout 1.0 - draft 04 "Is this a proper way to implement the flow?" Or the handling of the situation when the user " the user wants to revoke access to the Android app from another device".